# How to : login,each user to have a gridview with his information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

- I'm wondering if someone would help me with some ideas.

  - I want to make after a user is logging with a username and a pass
    from database to have on his page a gridview so he can add info in it
    and he infos are added in the database and so on.
  - Other users to have other gridview , so no one will
    have the same gridview. each one is separately .

Should I make a register page where on create account it's making a table with his username? this means to work with tables for each user or is there other way?

I will use sqldata source to get info from the tables in the gridview

Thanks,

Comment: not sure if i understand but let me repeat, u want user to login and based on their username and password u want them to go to different page?

Comment: No i want each user to have hos gridview with his info in it

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered leveraging the Personalization features of ASP.NET?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z36h8be9.aspx